# Plotting line color and style in matplotlib time-series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the foll. code to plot a time-series:

```
plt.plot_date(x=time_stamps, y=data[label], fmt='r-', linewidth=0.5, label=label)
```

However, I want to specify the line color and style separately instead of using fmt. is there a soln?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it separately like this:

```
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', color='r')
```